# Unsealed meat in freezer

Tags: food-safety, food-preservation

Below is my situation:

Is completely (vacuum) sealing leftover meat in the freezer absolutely necessary? I would always just use a plastic bag to cover the meat and fold it around couple of times so it's almost as good as sealed (usually grocery plastic bag is much bigger than the piece of meat) and have never had a problem with it last a decade or so I have been cooking.

But recently I got this new roommate who insists on me using special small plastic bags with sealers to use and he is being very paranoid, obsessive about it.

So my question is: Is he right?

Comment: How long are you storing the meat?

Comment: Typially anywhere between 2-3 weeks. I buy a piece of meat and cook like 4-5 times with it during said duration.

Comment: Your roommate is a nut; doubly so if you are not sharing food. If roommate wants to vacuum pack all his meat in the freezer, that will keep it safe from the imagined horrors of your meat. On the other hand, if he's paranoid enough to provide the bags and sealer,...

Comment: @Ecnerwal, that's exactly what I have been telling him, but he does not seem to listen.

Answer (score 2):

If you are noticing freezer burn or foreign odors/flavors with your loosely-wrapped meat, then you need to do a better job of storing it.

Your roommate may be in this habit because he is used to storing things in the freezer for a longer period.  2-3 weeks is longer than I would store something loosely wrapped like that in order to maintain good quality.

Comment: Thanks for answer. There is absolutely no freezer burn, let alone foriegn odors. From my experience, freezer burn only occurs in meats that are not wrapped whatsoever, and lying the freezer just by itself, but I have never done that in this apartment.